# SSL certificate invalid when attempting to clone repository using git2 on Android

Tags: rust, libgit2, git2-rs

I'm encountering an issue while trying to clone a repository using the git2 library on Android. Initially, I had trouble compiling OpenSSL for Android using Rust. However, I managed to successfully compile it by adding the following dependency to my Cargo.toml and using the NDK:

```
openssl = { version = "*", features = ["vendored"] }
```

After this, I attempted to clone a repository on Android, but I'm getting an error message stating.

```
the SSL certificate is invalid
```

I've verified that the same repository is accessible on other platforms like Windows and macOS.

Could you please guide me on how to address this SSL certificate issue on Android? I greatly appreciate your assistance!

Comment: It would help if you specified the server as well as the details of the certificate you are receiving.  That said, make sure your clock is right on the machine doing the clone.

Comment: I have the same error, let me know if you successfully resolved it. I things this might be related: https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git/issues/414